# Unity Unwanted Delay In Code Execution (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing for the car controller. but the torque transmission function is processed with a delay. that is, if you release the gas button, the car will continue to accelerate for some time. the same situation with braking and maximum speed. no matter what I did, it was not possible to fix this delay...

Video how it works:
[YouTube](https://youtu.be/u-EkwzNib9s)

C# code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VCC_MAIN : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Wheels Data")]
    public VCC_WHEEL FLWheel;
    public VCC_WHEEL FRWheel;
    public VCC_WHEEL RLWheel;
    public VCC_WHEEL RRWheel;
    public List<WheelCollider> drivableWC;

    [Header("Engine Data")]
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float engineTorque;
    public float brakePower;

    [Header("Rig Data")]
    public Transform centerOfMass;

    [Header("Debug Data")]
    public float verticalInput;
    public float currSpeed;
    [HideInInspector] public Rigidbody rig;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        rig = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rig.centerOfMass = transform.InverseTransformPoint(centerOfMass.transform.position);

        drivableWC.Add(RLWheel.GetComponent<WheelCollider>());
        drivableWC.Add(RRWheel.GetComponent<WheelCollider>());
    }
    
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        verticalInput = Mathf.Round(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        currSpeed = Mathf.Round(rig.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f);

        if (verticalInput != 0 && currSpeed < maxSpeed)
        {
            ApplyTorque(engineTorque);
            ApplyBrake(0);
        }
        else if (verticalInput == 0)
        {
            ApplyTorque(0);
            ApplyBrake(brakePower / 100f);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyTorque(float torque)
    {
        drivableWC[0].motorTorque = torque * verticalInput;
        drivableWC[1].motorTorque = torque * verticalInput;
    }

    private void ApplyBrake(float brake)
    {
        drivableWC[0].brakeTorque = brake;
        drivableWC[1].brakeTorque = brake;
    }
}
```

I tried to process everything in the update, it did not help.
"Input.GetAxisRow" is also not a matter of the result.

Comment: You may experience an issue with WheelCollider. so you might try to make changes in these method  ApplyBrake and ApplyTorque

Comment: how could i change these functions?

Comment: I have post an answer in which shows how to implement these changes in your code, try it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in the line

```
 currSpeed = Mathf.Round(rig.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f);
```

Try removing that Mathf.Round and use currSpeed as a float, so you can be more precise on the speed calculation.

Comment: this method also did not help(

Answer (score 0):

You may experience an issue with WheelCollider. so you might try to make changes in these method ApplyBrake and ApplyTorque

Try the below code and see if it works:

```
private float targetTorque;
    private float targetBrake;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        verticalInput = Mathf.Round(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        currSpeed = Mathf.Round(rig.velocity.magnitude * 3.6f);

        if (verticalInput != 0 && currSpeed < maxSpeed)
        {
            targetTorque = engineTorque * verticalInput;
            targetBrake = 0;
        }
        else if (verticalInput == 0)
        {
            targetTorque = 0;
            targetBrake = brakePower / 100f;
        }

        ApplyTorque(targetTorque);
        ApplyBrake(targetBrake);
    }

    private void ApplyTorque(float torque)
    {
        foreach (var wheel in drivableWC)
        {
            wheel.motorTorque = Mathf.Lerp(wheel.motorTorque, torque, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyBrake(float brake)
    {
        foreach (var wheel in drivableWC)
        {
            wheel.brakeTorque = Mathf.Lerp(wheel.brakeTorque, brake, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
```

Comment: tried your code. with "Time.deltaTime" the car does not move at all. but if write like this "wheel.motorTorque = Mathf.Lerp(wheel.motorTorque, torque, 1);", then everything becomes as it was ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to partially solve the problem by entering huge values of the forward friction at the wheels, but with these values the car behaves like a toy... maybe there is something wrong with my unity. maybe I didn't install some packages. although I seem to be doing everything as before, but before, exactly the same code worked as it should...

[image]